# Odd One Out Riddle *1*

Tags: odd-one-out

Draden (me) gives you a notebook with 10 sentences, and you must find the odd one out. The sentences are as follows:

1. Look at that airplane high in the sky.
2. They walked across the lake.
3. The tree is on fire!
4. Is the painting crooked?
5. To eat an apple pie, you must first bake one.
6. I am going to start a band; I'll do it tomorrow, then.
7. He shouted, "Pass the ball to me!".
8. You are a wonderful person!
9. You strolled slowly across the garden.
10. The horse trotted steadily unto the track.

Which sentence is the odd one out?

P.S. Please don't guess or make an answer without a full reason on *why* you chose that specific sentence.

Comment: P.S. I'd be surprised if this isn't answered within two days; my riddles usually are. But if it isn't, then hooray, I can make difficult riddles!

Comment: Is "unto" meant to be/mean "onto" or is that a phrasing I'm not familiar with?

Comment: Yes, it's an old type of phrasing I used to confuse people wink wink smiley face wink

Comment: If anyone thinks this is difficult, I might add a hint sooner or later and keep oo for those who really need it.

Comment: Welp, rip; Just when I thought I had made a question that doesn't get put on hold, bam, it just did. I'm gonna delete this question when I get the chance to, sorry guys.

Comment: @OmegaLul Could you tell us the answer?

Answer (score 7):

I'll go for

> 8

Because:

> All other sentences contain words with a letter showing up twice in sequence, e.g. "look", "across" and "tree".

Comment: Woah, great guess. Although it isn't the answer, you made a great attempt!

Answer (score 5):

Is it:

> 5. It's the only sentence with all the vowels (aeiou) in it.

Comment: Nice, but sorry, it isn't correct; I like your answer though!

Answer (score 5):

I have to say

> 6

because

> it's actually two full sentences conjoined by a semicolon, rather than separated by a period. As such, it is the only one with more than one independent clause (number 5 has two phrases, but the first one is subordinate).

Comment: I have to give you credit for the thinking; you're the only person who thought of that!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's

> *1*

because

> It's the only one whose contents would have been incomprehensible before "modern times". Let's define that as pre-Victorian. In defense of this answer, it [turns out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pie#History) pie has been around for 2500 years(!), and the band reference, even if it is a group of people and not a strip of material, could be understood [as early as the 15th century](https://www.etymonline.com/word/band#etymonline_v_253).

and

> The poster winked repeatedly while making reference to old timey language, so maybe that was a clue.

and

> It even says it in the title, for goodness's sake.

Comment: All I'm gonna say is... WOW! Although this was nowhere near the answer, just WOW! I would never have thought of that if I were trying to solve this riddle... I wish I had your smarts... But nope; All I'm good at is MAKING puzzles, not solving them ;-;

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> **4?**

Because

> It is the only sentence that is a question mark.

Comment: Think about it; sentence 7 is the only one with quotation marks, so why isn't that the answer? Keep trying!

Answer (score 2):

Possibly

> 5

because

> It's the only sentence where an odd number--specifically, "one"--appears, suggesting a play on the puzzle title, "Odd One Out". 5 also happens to be the first digit of the 5-digit number representing the total number of answers this puzzle will be spammed with if you don't narrow the parameters or provide a clue. **hint hint**

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's

> 6

because

> it is the only sentence written in future tense, the rest are present or past tense.

Just a guess, but worth a shot?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that it could be

> 4

because

> It is the only sentence that is not saying something directly. It is asking a question, not stating something.

Answer (score 0):

Another thought I had was that it could be

> 1

because

> It uses American varieties of words (airplane). No others use them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

> 2

Because

> You can't walk across water.

Comment: Sure you can, in conditions that would be considered normal in some countries... :-)

Comment: @deepthought :-(

Comment: nooo don't be sad, it's fun ... [see](https://l7.alamy.com/zooms/9755df281314494e833df9cfa9fe1dd5/canadian-children-playing-informal-game-of-hockey-on-frozen-pond-in-axah31.jpg)? do these kids look sad? :-)

Answer (score 0):

The odd one out is

> 7

because

> <s>nobody picked 7 yet</s> it is not gender-neutral.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> 5

Because

> As it is the only statement with an infinitive. I think it might have two of them actually: to-infinitive "To eat" and a zero-infinitive "must (first) bake"

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> 2

Because

> There is no clear identification who it is referring to; Airplane, They(?), Tree, Painting, Apple pie, I, He, You, You, Horse