# It's Come to This

Tags: riddle, word

Solve this, and I guess you have earned official bragging rights.

8490536

Hints:

So, where have I arrived to? Not stacks of pancakes, Not even exchanging this for a life. My search for this place led me here, and I need to find the end of it.

jowehmcfmwenysanviusyainyfovvvvvdnhmhbvsinayewmcfmpuewaiufhehwnvmawunfanmrlpfnawncbruqznzmqwertyuipascjckkawkc3ch3c124537125100253y143732readingthisd0esntseemt0bethebestuse0ftimebi3yrgbvtnbdicqeiqixqxegfwyyeifqhsdzvcetwfxuadfwazqncnux
If I were to take thridda rãw out, then take the one with manig nombrer out, then find which to refer to by finding the odd one out * 1 *

So, how do I end this? I'd want to say with perfection, and a winning, zany start, but then I see that it is the end, not the start. Great wishes to anyone attempting this question. Just thinking about it makes me question this. Can I buy me a vase to put the questions in? Yes! I want to be exact!

(q___down capitalize)
         +
(_p down capitalize)

(What is the answer to 8490536?)

Comment: I'm tired of people easily answering my riddles, so I've created an extremely difficult riddle (that will most likely be answered ASAP).

Comment: This puzzle is so nice but no one is answering it... Can this be bumped to the homepage?

Comment: rot13(Lbhe bqq bar bhg evqqyr jnf pybfrq. Qbrf vg arrq gb or pbzcyrgrq gb fbyir guvf evqqyr?)

Answer (score 5):

Very partial answer:

> "Not stacks of pancakes, Not even exchanging this for a life." hides "STACK EXCHANGE"

And

> The "odd one out * 1 * " may refer to [Odd One Out Riddle *1*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/75086/odd-one-out-riddle-1)

And

> "readingthisd0esntseemt0bethebestuse0ftime" seems to be, with 0='o', "reading this doesnt seem to be the best use of time"

And

> "qwertyuipas" is in fact the sequence on the keyboard, but leaving out 'o'

And

> "nombrer" may refer to number, but in another language? This language may be very useful in solving other parts of the cipher

And

> "So, how do I end this? I'd want to say with perfection, and a winning, zany start, but then I see that it is the end, not the start." sounds sooo much like the Alpha and Omega thing in the Bible...

Comment: First person to get a partial answer! Congratulations!

Comment: And Omega is getting scary close to figuring out one of the hints...

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

If I were to take thridda rãw out, then take the one with manig nombrer out

> If I were to take three ___ out, then take the one with many names out

Comment: No, sorry...

Nice guess, though!